# perl threads self detach

Tags: multithreading, perl, asynchronous

I'm pretty new to perl (and programming too) and were toying around with threads for the last couple of weeks and so far I understood that using them to perform some similar parallel tasks is descouraged - memory consumption is uncontrollable if your number of threads depends on some input values, and simply limiting that number and doing some interim joins seems pretty much silly.
So I've tried to trick threads to return me some values through queues followed by detaching those threads (and without actually joining them) - here's an example with parallel ping:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use NetAddr::IP;
use Net::Ping;
use Thread::Queue;
use Thread::Semaphore;
########## get my IPs from CIDR-notation #############
my @ips;
for my $cidr (@ARGV) {
    my $n = NetAddr::IP->new($cidr);
    foreach ( @{ $n->hostenumref } ) {
        push @ips, ( split( '/', $_ ) )[0];
    }
}

my $ping      = Net::Ping->new("icmp");
my $pq        = Thread::Queue->new( @ips, undef );    # ping-worker-queue
my $rq        = Thread::Queue->new();                 # response queue
my $semaphore = Thread::Semaphore->new(100);          # I hoped this may be usefull to limit # of concurrent threads

while ( my $phost = $pq->dequeue() ) {
    $semaphore->down();
    threads->create( { 'stack_size' => 32 * 4096 }, \&ping_th, $phost );
}

sub ping_th {
    $rq->enqueue( $_[0] ) if $ping->ping( $_[0], 1 );
    $semaphore->up();
    threads->detach();
}

$rq->enqueue(undef);

while ( my $alive_ip = $rq->dequeue() ) {
    print $alive_ip, "\n";
}
```

I couldn't find a fully comprehensive description of how threads->detach() should work from within a threaded subroutine and thought that this might work... and it does - if I do something in the main program (thread) that stretches it's lifetime (sleep does well), so all the detached threads finish up and enqueue their part to my $rq, otherwise it will run some threads collect their results to the queue and exit with warnings like:

```
Perl exited with active threads:
    5 running and unjoined
    0 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

Making the main program "sleep" for a while, once again, seems silly - is there no way to make threads do their stuff and detach ONLY after the actual threads->detach() call?
So far my guess is that threads->detach() inside a sub applies as soon as the thread is created and so this is not the way.
I tried this out with CentOSs good old v5.10.1. Should this change with modern v5.16 or v5.18 (usethreads-compiled)?

Comment: Btw, why you want to detach threads?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. If you want the threads to detach sooner, call `threads->detach()` sooner (Not that I understand why you want to detach the threads to begin with). Also, you can probably spawn a small number of worker threads and have them dequeue, instead of spawning a thread per queued element. This way you'll have fewer threads, and can defer joining until the work is done (e.g., by waiting until `!$pq->pending()`, or just joining all threads in the pool once you're done queuing the work)

Comment: I don't think detach is actually the tool for the job here, because you _are_ trying to collate the results as you go, and need to wait for every thread to finish before exiting.

Comment: I detach threads only to release memory
I don't see a reasonable way to join threads partially - I need to get the results back from threads asyncronously and release the memory those threads use as soon as they're done - so I don't want to push them all in an array and join that after all the threads were created - too much memory used even for 126 threads (with a /25 net from the example)
If it was possible to join a thread as soon as it's done (from within the sub) that would be perfect

Comment: `foreach my $thr ( threads -> list ( threads::joinable ) ) { $thr -> join() }`

Answer (score 7):

Detaching a thread isn't particularly useful,  because you're effectively saying 'I don't care when they exit'.

This isn't typically what you want - your process is finishing with thread still running.

Generally though - creating threads has an overhead, because your processs is cloned in memory. You want to avoid doing this. `Thread::Queue` is also good to use, because it's a thread safe way of transferring information. In your code, you don't actually need it for `$pq` because you're not actually threading at the point where you're using it.

Your semaphore is one approach to doing it, but can I suggest as an alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Thread::Queue;

my $nthreads = 100;

my $ping_q = Thread::Queue -> new(); 
my $result_q = Thread::Queue -> new(); 

sub ping_host {
     my $pinger = Net::Ping->new("icmp");
     while ( my $hostname = $ping_q -> dequeue() ) {
         if ( $pinger -> ping ( $hostname, 1 ) ) { 
              $result_q -> enqueue ( $hostname ); 
         }
     }
}

#start the threads

for ( 1..$nthreads ) {
     threads -> create ( \&ping_host );
}

#queue the workload
$ping_q -> enqueue ( @ip_list );

#close the queue, so '$ping_q -> dequeue' returns undef, breaking the while loop. 

$ping_q -> end();

#wait for pingers to finish.
foreach my $thr ( threads -> list() ) {
   $thr -> join();
}
$results_q -> end();

#collate results
while ( my $successful_host = $results_q -> dequeue_nb() ) {
    print $successful_host, "\n"; 
}
```

This way you spawn the threads up front, queue the targets and then collate the results when you're done. You don't incur the overhead for repeatedly respawning threads, and you program will wait until all the threads are done. Which may be a while, because the ping timeout on a 'down' host will be quite a while.

Comment: Although I still don't quiet understand the difference between **$q->end()** and **$q->enqueue(undef)** - I thought those were the same, but somehow my threads wouldn't join up unless I end()-ed my queues

Comment: You need to `enqueue()` more `undef`s. Otherwise the first thread to get to it will remove it with it's dequeue, and the others will block waiting for more elements to come through the queue. `end` closes a queue, such that `dequeue` stops being blocking, and just returns `undef`.

Comment: thanks - that's what I suspected, when I saw just one thread joining

Answer (score 1):

Since detached threads can't be joined, you can wait for threads to finish their jobs,

```
sleep 1 while threads->list();
```

Comment: I'd suggest though - if you're doing this - then it may be as easy to _not_ detach the threads and instead join them.